# Is Ice Man [Bobby Drake] an only child?

Tags: marvel, x-men, iceman

Speaking mostly here of the "main" 616 universe, because I know it can vary, but other versions with siblings would be interesting to see.

The reason I ask is because, for Bobby especially, these relatives seem to "pop up" and then are casually forgotten. Jean, Gambit, Lorna, Sam Guthrie (to the *nth* power!), Scott, of course, and a number of other X-Men all have siblings that have (more or less) been kept canon. Bobby Drake's seem to constantly "shift" though.

The first mention of a sibling I remember was in the 1980s  **Spiderman and his Amazing Friends** cartoon. He had a sister who was also a mutant with light-based powers, called Light- Wave, seen here:

[image]

[image]

She's in one single episode, and never mentioned again. I know we can't really take this show as canon, though; Bobby was also "weak" against heat and *blazingly* straight in that version.

The next big instance was in **X-2: X-Men United,** where we see his either jealous, scared or just plain *dick* of a younger brother, Ronnie, sell him and his friends out to the police. I always thought that was because unlike Bobby, he was a Flat Scan.

[image]

Again, we can't take this as canon, because, 1, it's a movie, and 2 his parents were *Surprised* at his mutancy; canonically, Bobby and Hank were two X-Men who had full use of their mutations from *birth.*

I recently came across an old [90s] comic, where both X-Men strike forces were taking on Cortez and the Acolytes, and Bobby was making a massive snowball to launch at Piotyr because when Bobby had offered some kind, if clumsy words of comfort about his sister Illyana, Piotyr basically brushed him off saying he wouldn't understand because he was an "only child".

So it got me to wondering...

*Is* Bobby the only child in main universe?

What about other versions?

Is this something like in some continuities, Scott is the *older* Summers brother, where in others, *Alex* is?

Answer (score 4):

Marvel site doesn't list siblings amongst his known relatives, but there is a disclaimer that this is crowdsourced information and not from their own editors. https://www.marvel.com/characters/iceman

> Known Relatives
>   William Robert Drake (father), Madeline Beatrice Bass Drake (mother), Mary (cousin), Joel (cousin), Anne (aunt)